# Error 500: Closure.rehydrate at deploying grails app on cloud foundry

Tags: grails, cloud-foundry

recently tried to deploy a grails-app to cloud foundry, the app is running perfectly @ localhost but after `cf-push` with cloud-foundry plugin, the console is stuck at Starting application and when trying to acces url: myapp.cloudfoundry.com, i have:

```
Error 500 - Internal Server Error.

groovy.lang.Closure.rehydrate(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lgroovy/lang/Closure;
```

What does mean this error ?

edit: here are the logs:

```
==== logs/stderr.log ====
Aug 10, 2012 3:28:24 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-19820
Aug 10, 2012 3:28:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 386 ms
Aug 10, 2012 3:28:24 PM org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm setContainer
INFO: Set JAAS app name Catalina
Aug 10, 2012 3:28:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Aug 10, 2012 3:28:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.35
Aug 10, 2012 3:28:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT
Aug 10, 2012 3:28:33 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-19820
Aug 10, 2012 3:28:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 9331 ms

==== logs/stdout.log ====
```

Comment: Hi, do you have the VMC command line utility installed? Can you use this to retrieve the logs for the application?

Comment: Thanks for you attention, added logs in the first post! Notice that i had to kill the process during push ...

Comment: If you can make the application source available I can stage it myself and take a look. You can send it to support@cloudfoundry.com if you wish or make it available however you wish.

Comment: At cloudfoundry, we would like to help you with this problem. The problem seems to indicate a problem with the source, and if you need privacy you can open a ticket at cloudfoundry support. We may need to see at least a portion of your app. When we have the answer, we will post it here.

Comment: On your question above "What does this error mean?", it looks like stdout messages are being reported to the error logs which isn't giving us much information. Here are some ideas, 1) deploy a sample app to insure things are working, 2) simplify your app to the point where it deploys successfully, 3) incrementally enable additional functionality until it breaks, 4) try to use available tools like debug in STS to investigate further, http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/tools/STS/debugging-CF-Eclipse.html

Comment: I am seeing this error myself now with a Grails 2.0.4 app just deployed to CloudFoundry. I've previously deployed a separate Grails app to CF with no issue.

Answer (score 1):

On your question above "What does this error mean?", it looks like stdout messages are being reported to the error logs which isn't giving us much information. Here are some ideas, 1) deploy a sample app to insure things are working, 2) simplify your app to the point where it deploys successfully, 3) incrementally enable additional functionality until it breaks, 4) try to use available tools like debug in STS to investigate further, [cloudfoundry docs](http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/tools/STS/debugging-CF-Eclipse.html)

Answer (score 0):

This may be the same problem as stated in this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12469996/187812

The answer in that thread was that "Closure.rehydrate was introduced in Groovy 1.8.5", and the questioner had an older version of Groovy associated with their project.