# Grails start up error: groovy.lang.Closure.rehydrate(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lgroovy/lang/Closure;

Tags: grails, ubuntu, tomcat6, elasticsearch

I'm getting the following error when starting a Grails 2.1.0 app on Tomcat 6 / Ubuntu 12.04.

```
Error 500 - Internal Server Error.

groovy.lang.Closure.rehydrate(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lgroovy/lang/Closure;
```

This app runs fine using `run-app` in STS 3.0 on Windows 7 and also using Tomcat6 on Windows.

I've deployed the `war` manually.

I've seen a similar issue reported for an app deployed to Cloud Foundry:
[Error 500: Closure.rehydrate at deploying grails app on cloud foundry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904385/error-500-closure-rehydrate-at-deploying-grails-app-on-cloud-foundry) but nothing there is giving me any clues.

The app has worked fine previously. I've made a number of code changes recently, including installing the ElasticSearch plugin but the error in the logs is referring to building the views from the `gsps`.

```
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'grails'
17-Sep-2012 11:34:47 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet grails threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: groovy.lang.Closure.rehydrate(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lgroovy/lang/Closure;
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.GroovyPageTagBody.<init>(GroovyPageTagBody.java:65)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.GroovyPageTagBody.<init>(GroovyPageTagBody.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPage.createTagBody(GroovyPage.java:630)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPage$createTagBody.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:44)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:153)
    at gsp_bipboxindex_gsp.run(index.gsp:4)
```

Any clues much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Closure.rehydrate](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/Closure.html#rehydrate%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) was introduced in Groovy 1.8.5 . It looks like there is an older version of groovy in the war. Check the WEB-INF/lib directory inside your war file to see if it contains an duplicate and older version of groovy.

Comment: This might be related to the problem if you are using maven: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9406

Comment: In `WEB_INF\lib` I've got `groovy-all-1.8.6.jar` and `groovy-1.7.12-SNAPSHOT.jar`. I think the groovy 1.7 was added by the `ElasticSearch` module...

Comment: Works fine on deleting the `groovy-1.7.12-SNAPSHOT.jar` which was added by `ElasticSearch`. I'll have to change `Build.groovy` to exclude this.

Answer (score 0):

To others who are encountering this issue. David's comment on Sept 18 is correct, there are times where your plugins will bring in older versions of Groovy which are not supported on some servers. Here is what you need to do to fix this:

Find these entries Within BuildConfig.groovy, and add in a line to exclude groovy.

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    inherits("global") {
        excludes "groovy" //ADD THIS LINE
}
```